# How can I watch ngSrc of an img element and get the new width and height inside of my custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

index.html snippet:

```
<img ng-src="{{ImageURL}}"  my-image/>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtl', function($scope) {

  $scope.ImageURL = "";
  $scope.ImgWidth = 0;

  $scope.setImgSrc = function(imgURL) {
    $scope.ImageURL = imgURL;
  };

  $scope.setImgSrc('http://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-large.png');

});

app.directive('myImage', [function() {

  return function(scope, elm, attrs) {

    scope.$watch(elm.width(), function(newValue, oldValue) {

      scope.ImgWidth = newValue; // always returns 0!

    });

  };

}]);
```

Here's the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nrve6N7i94N1BwMKFscU?p=preview).  How can I get the new dimensions of the `img` element inside of my custom directive when `ngSrc` changes?  I have a feeling I'm not properly invoking `scope.$watch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the watch in your plunk is correct, though the example on SO is not, and neither may do what you expect.

A watch expression should be either a string expression or a function. In your example you are trying to watch the result of `elm.width()`...which is most likely 0. This is essentially equivalent to saying `scope.$watch(0, function() {...})`. If you want to watch the width you would need to do `scope.$watch(function() { return elm.width(); }, function() {...})` though it is a bad idea to hit the DOM so often, especially from a watch expression.

A better idea is to wait until the image is loaded (using the `load` event) and update the measurements at this point. The DOM will only be hit when your image is updated. I have updated the plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GgxOwp1xMHipQ5WmoyPR?p=preview).

Comment: Forgot to mention, the alternative to using full jQuery is to use elm[0].offsetWidth

Comment: One could also call `scope.$watch(elm.width, function() {...});`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your call to $watch. $watch expects the first argument to be either a string to be eval-ed or a function that it can call and then check the value of. You're passing it an integer instead. Try this:

```
 scope.$watch(function() { return elm.width(); }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
     scope.ImgWidth = newValue;
 });
```

Plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/93SvAosQWkQzRq0DFXaK?p=preview

Note, to get the width() function you also need to include the full jQuery, which I've done in my plunk.

**Update -** plunk updated to follow @Andyrooger's suggestion of handling the load event. Even better would be just to grab the width in the load event handler, but I've left it as-is to remain in the spirit of the question regarding $watch.

Comment: Ha, I like how you used $timeout in your plunk.  Great minds think alike or did you see that I was trying it out and added it also?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and running the plunk again. If the image is not already cached then the `$apply` run as part of the `$timeout` will not be able to grab the correct element width. The `$watch` doesn't get run until the next `$apply` so you would need to run an `$apply` when the image loads to update.

Comment: Missing the nifty idea of demonstration with `$timeout` though ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is proabably unnoticable because the image is so small, but you are getting the width before the image has loaded. To fix that, you add an on load to the element

```
app.directive('myImage', [function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      elm.on('load', function()
      {
        scope.ImgWidth = $(this).width();
        scope.$apply();
      });
    };
}]);
```